# 96% confidence interval and confidence interval of 96th percentile

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

May I ask is 96% confidence interval and confidence interval of 96th percentile the same? If so, may I ask why?

Comment: What distribution are we talking about? Standard normal distribution? And what is your confidence interval(symmetric about the mean)?

Comment: The only information I am being given is The 96th percentile confidence interval for the number of active connections on a web server is given
by the interval [16 ± 1.5]. This confidence interval was computed using 40 observations of the web server.It does not indicate what distribution it has.

Comment: The formulation is ambiguous. In general, the $96^{\text{th}}$ percentile is the argument of the cumulative distribution for which the total area (total probability) is equal to $96\%$. The $96\%$ confidence interval can be equal to the percentile if it is the one-sided confidence interval. If it is two-sided like in your comment then both are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

A 96% confidence interval is where we think the true value of some statistical measure lie, based on observations. You could say that we are 96% certain that the true value lies inside the confidence interval.

A 96th percentile is the level below which 96% of the data lies, and it is one of those true values I mentioned in the above paragraph (along with mean, standard deviation, and so on). We can estimate where that is based on our data, and we can find a confidence interval, meaning a range of values such that we are *pretty certain* the true 96th percentile lies within there somewhere. A 5% confidence interval of the 96th percentile is a narrow region around our estimate (we are only 5% certain that the true 96th percentile lies there), while a 90% confidence interval of the 96th percentile is a relatively large region.

To analyze the statement you gave in the comments, there is some *true* value $x$ such that 96% of the time, the number of active connections is below $x$, and using those 40 observations they are quite certain that that true value lies between $14.5$ and $17.5$.

The fact that what they're measuring (as far as I can see) is discrete (you can only have an integer number of connections at any one time) makes this somewhat confusing, but it seems that they are pretending that the observations take continuous values in order to make the analysis easier.